# Getting form data from PHP to MSSQL database

Tags: php

I am creating a Database request form that will take requests from the requestor for a particular database on our network, run a randomizer script on it that will clear all user confidential information, and then send it to the requestor (support personnel or developer) for access and review.
I am using PowerShell to generate a list of databases we have across all servers on the network and saving that information into a database which is then accessed by PHP.

I have 2 pages setup as below.

Index.php

```
<!doctype HTML>
<?php  
    $server="database server";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"database", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"password");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo);
    if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
?>
<html>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/styles.css' />
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Client Database Request Portal</title>
    <header> 
        <h1 align="center">Client Database Request Portal</h1>
    </header>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<form action="request.php" method="post">
  <div class="elem-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="requestor" placeholder="John Doe" pattern=[A-Z\sa-z]{3,20} required>
  </div>
  <div class="elem-group">
    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="requestor_email" placeholder="john.doe@email.com" required>
  </div>
  <div class="elem-group">
    <label for="database-selection">Database:</label>
        <select>
          <option>Select a Database</option>
            <?php 
            $sql = "SELECT DatabaseName, DatabaseServer FROM databases";
            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option>'.$row['DatabaseName'].'</option>';
            }   
            ?>
          </select>
    </div>
  <div class="elem-group">
    <label for="randomize-database">Randomize Database?</label>
    <input type="radio" id="Yes" name="Yes" Value="Yes" checked>Yes</input>
    <input type="radio" id="No" name="No" Value="No" disabled>No</input>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
 <?php sqlsrv_close( $conn );?>
<form action="request.php" method="POST">
</body>
</html>
```

Request.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php  
        $server="database server";
        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"database", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"password");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo);
        if( $conn ) {
         echo "Connection established.<br />";
        }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
?>
<html>
  
<head>
    <title>Request page</title>
</head>
  
<body>
    <center>
        <?php $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $name =  $_REQUEST['requestor'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['requestor_email'];
        $database =  $_REQUEST['DatabaseName'];
        //$randomize = $_REQUEST['randomize-database'];
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.requests VALUES ('$name', 
            '$email','$database', $timestamp)";
          
        if(sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql)){
            echo "<h3>data stored in a database successfully." 
                . " Please browse your localhost php my admin" 
                . " to view the updated data</h3>"; 
  
            echo nl2br("\$name\n $email\n "
                . "$database\n $randomize");
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Hush! Sorry $sql. " 
                . sqlsrv_error($conn);
        }
          
        // Close connection
       sqlsrv_close($conn);?>
    </center>
</body>
  
</html>
```

I need help setting or forwarding those variables from index.php to request.php because right now it shows success but nothing is written in the database, as well as figuring out a way to download  or backup the selected database run a query on it and upload it to dropbox (which can be done via API)

Comment: When you debug, can you narrow down one specific thing which isn't working as expected?  At a glance it looks like you just forgot to give your `<select>` element a `name` attribute, so it's not going to sent its value in the POST request.

Comment: You are wide open to SQL injection. Use prepared statements

Comment: @David thanks that helped, it now lists the database. when I print in PHP. But still does not log items into the database.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid SQL injection to start with, use the syntax like in this example:

```php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO accounts (username, engine, access, gender, project) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $_SESSION['name'], $_POST['engine'], $_SESSION['access'], $_POST['gender'], $_POST['project']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

In my example you see that I use `POST` and `SESSION` variables, which is inserted into the database. You can also use `GET`.

A simple POST form example

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="access"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="engine"/> <!--- This is hidden --->
  <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you want the `bind_result()` and `fetch()` for after running an INSERT :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Haha thats true, just wrote this, and was thinking about a simple select.. Will edit it, thanks.